# How to fit ordinary differential equations to empirical data?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, optimization, time-series, empirical-processes

For some biological systems, there exists ordinary or partial differential equations that allow one to simulate their activity/behavior over time. Some of these models even produce data that is very difficult to tell apart from real data.

What I haven't been able to figure out is how were those equations found? Suppose I have some empirical time-series data, that has very little noise in it. How could I "fit" or find ODEs or PDEs that mimic them?

Are there any paper and pen based methods for this? Or is this something that you would do numerically; say measure the difference between the output of a given ODE and empirical data and optimize the parameters?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are methods to do so - here is an approach that I have found, see [here](https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/CalibratingODEs.html). Though, you typically have to try and find an ode/pde model that exhibit similar enough behaviour to try and fit the model. First tip is try to plot a phase plane diagram and see if there are features you can make use of i.e. obtain a function that is $f(y', y) = k$ .

Comment: Do you already know the form of the ODE or PDE you wish to fit, and just need to estimate the parameters? This is a very active field - in applied math it is often called an "inverse problem" in or for differential equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering a basic introductory example involving ODEs we can present the problem as.

Given the dynamic system

$$
\cases{
\dot x = f(x,t,\theta)\\
y = h(x,t,\theta)
}
$$

with initial conditions $x(0)=g(\theta)$

with $x = (x_1,\cdots,x_n), \ y = (y_1\cdots,y_m), \ \theta=(\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_p)$. Here $h()$ is the observation function and $\theta$ the unknown parameters. The measured data are the points $(t_k, \bar y_k), \{k = 1,\cdots, N\}$

Find

$$
\theta^* = \arg\min\cal{E}(\theta)
$$

with

$$
\cal{E}(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\bar y_{i,j}-y_i(t_j,\theta))^2
$$

Methods using the steepest descent direction can be used to find $\theta^*$. Those methods use the error gradient direction or

$$
\Delta_{\theta} \cal{E}(\theta) = \sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{i=1}^{i=m}(\bar y_{i,j}-y_i(t_j))\frac{\partial y_i(t_j,\theta)}{\partial\theta}
$$

or

$$
\Delta_{\theta} \cal{E}(\theta) = \sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{i=1}^{i=m}(\bar y_{i,j}-h_i(x,t_j,\theta))\frac{\partial h_i(x,t_j,\theta)}{\partial\theta}
$$

here the quantities

$$
\frac{\partial h_i(x,t_j,\theta)}{\partial \theta}
$$

are calculated as follows.

$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
  \frac{\partial\dot x}{\partial\theta} & = & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\\
       \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} & = & \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial \theta}
\end{array}
$$

now calling

$$
s^x_{\theta}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta},\ \ s^y_{\theta}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
$$

we have

$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
  \dot s^x_{\theta} & = & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}s^x_{\theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\\
       s^y_{\theta} & = & \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}s^x_{\theta}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial \theta}
\end{array}
$$

having unknown initial conditions, then also

$$
s^x_{\theta}(0)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}
$$

- Case study. Consider the dynamic system

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
  \dot v & = & c(v-\frac{1}{3}v^3+r)  \\
  \dot r & = & -\frac{1}{c}(v-a+b r) \\
     y_1 & = & v \\
     y_2 & = & r
\end{array}
$$

with $v(0)=v_0,\ r(0)=r_0$

We have $\theta=\{a,b,c,v_0, r_0\}$. $x=\{x_1,x_2\}=\{v,r\}$, $\theta=\{\theta_1,\dots,\theta_5\}$, $h_1 = x_1,\ \ h_2 = x_2$ and $x_1(0)=\theta_4,\ x_2(0)=\theta_5$, $y=\{y_1,y_2\}$

then

$$
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
    \theta _3 \left(1-x_1^2\right) & \theta_3       \\
               -\frac{1}{\theta_3} & -\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_3} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0          &             0             & -\frac{1}{3} x_1^3+x_1+x_2 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\theta_3}  & -\frac{x_2}{\theta _3} & \frac{-\theta_1+x_1+\theta _2 x_2}{\theta_3^2} & 0 &  0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The procedure to obtain the error gradient is as follows:

1. Given a vector of parameters $\theta_k$, integrate $x^k=x(t,\theta_k)$ , $y^k= y(t,\theta_k)$,$s^x_{\theta}(t,\theta_k)$ and $s^y_{\theta}(t,\theta_k)$
2. Calculate $\Delta_{\theta} \cal{E}(\theta_k)$

The following set of DEs, solve the items (1,2)

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
  x_1' & = & \theta_3 \left(-\frac{1}{3}x_1^3+x_1+x_2\right) \\
  x_2' & = & -\frac{-\theta_1+\theta_2 x_2+x_1}{\theta_3} \\
  \underset{1}{\overset{1}{s_x}}' & = & \theta_3\underset{1}{\overset{2}{s_x}}+\theta_3\underset{1}{\overset{1}{s_x}}\left(1-x_1^2\right) \\
  \underset{2}{\overset{1}{s_x}}' & = & \theta_3\underset{2}{\overset{2}{s_x}}+\theta_3\underset{2}{\overset{1}{s_x}}\left(1-x_1^2\right) \\
  \underset{3}{\overset{1}{s_x}}' & = & \theta_3\underset{3}{\overset{2}{s_x}}+\theta_3\underset{3}{\overset{1}{s_x}}\left(1-x_1^2\right)-\frac{1}{3}
   x_1^3+x_1+x_2 \\
  \underset{4}{\overset{1}{s_x}}' & = & \theta_3\underset{4}{\overset{2}{s_x}}+\theta_3\underset{4}{\overset{1}{s_x}}\left(1-x_1^2\right) \\
  \underset{5}{\overset{1}{s_x}}' & = & \theta_3\underset{5}{\overset{2}{s_x}}+\theta_3\underset{5}{\overset{1}{s_x}}\left(1-x_1^2\right) \\
  \underset{1}{\overset{2}{s_x}}' & = &
  \frac{1}{\theta_3}-\frac{\underset{1}{\overset{1}{s_x}}}{\theta_3}-\frac{\theta_2\underset{1}{\overset{2}{s_x}}}{\theta_3}\\
  \underset{2}{\overset{2}{s_x}}' & = & -\frac{\underset{2}{\overset{1}{s_x}}}{\theta_3}-\frac{\theta_2 \underset{2}{\overset{2}{s_x}}}{\theta_3}-\frac{x_2}{\theta_3}\\
  \underset{3}{\overset{2}{s_x}}' & = & -\frac{\underset{3}{\overset{1}{s_x}}}{\theta_3}-\frac{\theta_2 \underset{3}{\overset{2}{s_x}}}{\theta_3}+\frac{-\theta_1+\theta_2 x_2+x_1}{\theta_3^2}\\
  \underset{4}{\overset{2}{s_x}}' & = & -\frac{\underset{4}{\overset{1}{s_x}}}{\theta_3}-\frac{\theta_2 \underset{4}{\overset{2}{s_x}}}{\theta_3}\\
  \underset{5}{\overset{2}{s_x}}' & = & -\frac{\underset{5}{\overset{1}{s_x}}}{\theta_3}-\frac{\theta_2 \underset{5}{\overset{2}{s_x}}}{\theta_3}\\
\end{array}
$$

with initial conditions

$$
\begin{array}{c}
  x_1(0) = \theta_4, x_2(0) = \theta_5 \\
  \underset{1}{\overset{1}{s_x}}(0) = 0,\underset{2}{\overset{1}{s_x}}(0) = 0,\underset{3}{\overset{1}{s_x}}(0) = 0,\underset{4}{\overset{1}{s_x}}(0) = 1,\underset{5}{\overset{1}{s_x}}(0) = 0\\ \\
  \underset{1}{\overset{2}{s_x}}(0) = 0,\underset{2}{\overset{2}{s_x}}(0)= 0,\underset{3}{\overset{2}{s_x}}(0) = 0,\underset{4}{\overset{2}{s_x}}(0) = 0,\underset{5}{\overset{2}{s_x}}(0) = 1
\end{array}
$$

There are many variants involving the smoothing process. We can utilize instead of minimum square error, other statistical error measures like the maximum likelyhood estimation, etc.

The following [reference](https://dblp.uni-trier.de/pers/hd/h/Hasenauer:Jan) is a good step into the smoothing problem. Those smoothing problems involving DE's parameters determination are also known as **inverse problems**