# How to identify linear non-homogenous ODE from data?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, dynamical-systems, parameter-estimation, linear-regression

I want to fit a model
$$\overset{\cdot} x = Ax + v(t)Bx + Cu(t)$$

to data, where $u(t),v(t)$ are known inputs and $A,B,C$ should be fitted. The data are assumed to be drawn from the above model but with an $i.i.d.$ noise, that is for the data $y_t$ we would have
$$y_t = x(t) + \eta$$
$$\eta \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$

Now I want to use linear regression to fit the model to the above data. Is it an appropiate approach to use
$$ \overset{\cdot}{y_t} \approx \frac{y_{t+1}-y_{t}}{\delta t} =: z_t$$

and then use linear regression for
$$z_t | y_t = Ay_t + v_tBy_t + Cu_t + \eta_z$$

with $\eta_z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{2 \sigma^2}{(\delta t)^2})$?

Or should I not make this approximation? (In the simple 1-d case of no input one could e.g. fit an equation of the form $\ln y_t = at  + \ln x0$, i.e. using the explicit solution, but I don't see how to generalize this)

Any help would be appreciated, also I would be glad for some link where exactly this special case is treated. (Most ressources I find are rather detailed info on system identification, which I think is too much for this simple case)

Comment: Please, have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3470910/how-to-fit-ordinary-differential-equations-to-empirical-data/3471135#3471135

Comment: thanks for the link! but that means I have to integrate an ode in any case? implementation-wise, I guess it will then not make too much difference if I just use some optimization method on $||y-x(A,B,C)||$ (where I integrate $x$)?

Answer (score 1):

As

$$
x(t) = C\exp \left(\int _0^t(A+B v(\eta ))d\eta \right)\int _0^t\exp \left(-\int _0^{\mu }(A+B v(\eta ))d\eta \right) u(\mu )d\mu +c_0 \exp \left(\int
   _0^t(A+B v(\eta ))d\eta \right)
$$

given the data points $\{t_k,x_k,k=1,\cdots,n\}$ we can form the error function

$$
\sum_k\|x_k-x(t_k)\|^2 = \mathcal{E}(A,B,C.c_0)
$$

and then proceed with a minimization method to find the minimum for $\mathcal{E}(A,B,C.c_0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is also what I thought at first but this seems way slower than the above approach (which is not necessarily an issue). Do you have a particular recommendation for an optimization method to use (ideally one that is already implemented somewhere in python)?

Comment: MATHEMATICA from Wolfram has a handy function called `ParametricNDSolve` which solves softly this kind of problem. Perhaps you can find something similar with Matlab. Those hints are concerning the integration issues. For minimization you can choose any nonlinear solver  steep descent based.

Comment: In Python you can find from `scipy`,  `optimize`.